# Is there any way to get the social account link in React Native?

Tags: react-native, twitter-oauth, instagram-api, facebook-authentication, social-media

I am developing an app with React Native and need to get Facebook, Twitter, Instagram account link when the user signups. And I need to send it to the server with API.
How can I get the account links? Should I add any SDK for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase auth for your app, refer the following link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Ok, I checked it and noticed the firebase supports the social auth. By the way, I can't see the Instagram auth there.